# Ruby benchmarking code. What am I seeing?

Tags: ruby

This is the code:

```
require 'active_support/json'
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'dalli'

client = Dalli::Client.new('localhost', namespace: 'json-bm', compress: true)

object = {
  id: 1000,
  published: false,
  posts: [
    { id: 2000, body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.' }
  ]
}

client.set("object-to-json", object.to_json)
client.set("object-as-json", object.as_json)

GC.disable

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('to_json') { client.get('object-to-json') }
  x.report('as_json') { client.get('object-as-json').to_json }
end
```

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
             to_json      1069 i/100ms
             as_json       507 i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
             to_json    10581.7 (±12.0%) i/s -     50243 in   5.039299s
             as_json     5089.4 (±0.9%) i/s -      25857 in   5.080955s
```

Storing and retrieving the string is, unsurprisingly, 2.1x faster than
retrieving the marshalled object and stringifying it every time it is
retrieved.

So are the numbers 1069 and 507 the number of times the code was run? What does i/100ms mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would say "iterations per 100ms"; but lets verify.

Running this code:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('to_json') { sleep 1 }
  x.report('as_json') { sleep 2 }
end
```

I get:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
             to_json     1.000  i/100ms
             as_json     1.000  i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
             to_json      1.000  (± 0.0%) i/s -      5.000 
             as_json      0.500  (± 0.0%) i/s -      3.000  in   6.000514s
```

This is slightly different from what you have − probably due to a different version of the gem.

The output of the "Calculating" block is [described on the homepage](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips):

> Benchmark/ips will report the number of iterations per second for a given block of code. When analyzing the results, notice the percent of standard deviation which tells us how spread out our measurements are from the average. A high standard deviation could indicate the results having too much variability.

So here my `to_json` ran once per second with no deviation between the results; my `as_json` ran 0.5 times per second also with no deviation in the results.

Unfortunately, [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/benchmark-ips) gives a 503, but by [searching the code](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=i%2F100ms) I found the [`warmup_stats()`](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips/blob/d1e2d0b41eefc0983dd3b6a50a2454bd802f9107/lib/benchmark/ips/job/stdout_report.rb#L17) method which gets called from the [`run_warmup()`](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips/blob/ff56c078efbe1eac46fc3ccc5c79da44568a004b/lib/benchmark/ips/job.rb#L190) method; abbreviated both functions read:

```
def warmup_stats(_warmup_time_us, timing)
  $stdout.printf "%s i/100ms\n", Helpers.scale(timing)
end

def run_warmup
  before = Time.now
  target = Time.now + @warmup

  warmup_iter = 0

  while Time.now < target
    item.call_times(1)
    warmup_iter += 1
  end

  after = Time.now

  warmup_time_us = time_us before, after
  @timing[item] = cycles_per_100ms warmup_time_us, warmup_iter
  @stdout.warmup_stats warmup_time_us, @timing[item]
end
```

In other words, it first "warms up" various disk caches, CPU caches, and such by running the block for `@warmup` time, and reports for many iterations it ran. In my  example, just once since my code is so "slow". It then reports how many `cycles_per_100ms` were run during the warmup with a minimum of 1 cycle.

You can mostly ignore the warmup figures, in your example we can see that 1069 i/100ms and 507 i/100ms warmup numbers are roughly the same as the 10581.7 i/s and 5089 i/s results. It might be useful in some cases though, and a large difference might indicate that the performance is significantly improved by some caching.